# How to do log in test using Jmeter for web app which uses Cognito?

Tags: amazon-web-services, performance, testing, jmeter, amazon-cognito

While logging in, web app uses Amazon Cognito and gets tokens to authenticate. The problem is, the tokens expire every hour and the test works properly only for an hour. The tokens aren't coming in response in any previous HTTP request so that I could make a correlation. My question is how to get the tokens? I know there is an endpoint described here: https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/cognito/latest/developerguide/token-endpoint.html but I still don't know how to get the parameters which I have to put in the request.

Answer (score 0):

This Token Endpoint is for exchanging the authorization code for a token.

In its turn authorization code can be obtained from the [AUTHORIZATION Endpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/authorization-endpoint.html) which can return the token by the way.

You need to know only `client_id` which can be obtained from the [User Pool App Client](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-settings-client-apps.html)

Check out [How to Run Performance Tests on OAuth Secured Apps with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-performance-tests-oauth-secured-apps-jmeter/) article for more information, it's about [OAuth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth) in general but it's partially applicable for your login challenge.

Comment: Yes, thank you! It worked when I used the /oauth2/authorize endpoint and in the parameters response_type=token. After that, I was redirected to kind of login page, where I entered my credentials and as a result I received the access token in the response header (location). Thank's for your help again